# Is there .exe package of apache tomcat somewhere?

Tags: installation, tomcat

I only see binary packages on apache website. Where can I find windows installer? I downloaded old version from some user of code.google.com, but that's definitely not the way they distribute it. I believe that I am just not seeing obvious things best then there is no tomcat installers in whole web. What I am doing wrong? Desperate already =)

Comment: Do you have any problems running `APACHE_BASE\bin\catalina.bat`?

Comment: did not know about this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Windows Service Installer for Tomcat 7 from [this link](http://apache.sunsite.ualberta.ca/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.47/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.exe). The link is taken from [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

For Tomcat 8, look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi).

Comment: this is what I've been looking for and not seeing all this time. I knew it was right in front of my eyes.